# how to change background color of a cell of table depending on some particular analog value coming from arduino

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Arduino ajax LED Button Control</title>
    <script>
            var sensor_val = 0;
            
           function GetArduinoIO()
 {
  nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
   if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
     if (this.responseXML != null) 
                                             {
      // XML file received - contains analog values, switch values and LED states
      var count;
                                                   
                        //sensor value read
                                                    document.getElementById("sensor").innerHTML =
                                                             this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('sensor')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
sensor_val = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('sensor')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                 }
                                           }                
    }
   }
  }
  // send HTTP GET request with LEDs to switch on/off if any
  request.open("GET", "ajax_inputs" +  nocache, true);
  request.send(null);
  setTimeout('GetArduinoIO()', 1000);
               
            }
</script>
<style>
 .IO_box {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  width: 120px;
 }
 h1 {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: blue;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 }
 h2 {
  font-size: 85%;
  color: #5734E6;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
 }
 p, form, button {
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #252525;
 }
 .small_text {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #737373;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="GetArduinoIO()">
    <h1>Arduino >>>TISHITU<<< LED Button "IOT"</h1>
         <div class="IO_box">
                     <h2>sensor value</h2>
                     <p> A0: <span id="sensor">...</span></p>
            </div>
            <table border=3px width=50% cellpadding=10>
              <tr>
                 <td id="r1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">0-10%</td>
                
              </tr>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working on IOT and i want to change the color of table cell to red color if the incoming value from arduino i.e.,sensor_val lies between 200 to 300. my html code is as follows .please suggest me how should i apply condition of sensor_val to change the color of cell of table ie td with id"r1".

Comment: If you can append that value as an attribute to the element in question you can use that as a selector to declare your style rules. Or just run a conditional statement to determine if the value lies between the specified amount and append a class if the check evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to the relevant part of your code.

```
if(sensor_val>=200 && sensor_val<=300){
document.getElementById("sensor").style.backgroundColor='red';
}
```

I would have added to your code snippet, but it is not working...